# Does HLDA in Mallet return Word-Topic Distribution?

Tags: topic-modeling, mallet, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to generate a taxonomy of extracted terminology using topic models. Therefore, I had to use Hierarchical Latent Dirichlet allocation.
However, after getting the topics tree, I would like to annotate topics but I am unable to produce the word-topic distribution in Mallet. 
I have checked the parameters, it seems as if the only output file I can get is the output state, and it doesn't show the needed information.

I am using mallet implementation from the command window, I am using the following command line:

```
bin/mallet run cc.mallet.topics.tui.HierarchicalLDATUI --input my_corpus.mallet --output-state topic-statehlda.txt
```

I managed to get the **topic-statehlda.txt** which contains all the topic paths for the words and I have also visualized it (an example of the topics tree [TopicsTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pUTL.png)- terms where trimmed because they make the tree big and difficult to navigate). Some terms occur in multiple topics so that is why I am interested in the word-topic distribution to be able to select the most representative ones.

Can you please advise? is there a way to retrieve topics labels in a different way?

I am applying HLDA over documents from the same topic, and I am only using HLDA to extract possible taxonomies over a list of automatically extracted terminology (noun phrases), does this look meaningful or is it a bad practice?

The corpus is a collection of OCR'ed insurance documents. An Example of my automatically extracted taxonomy is:

> motor insurance policy, motor policy schedule, motorcycle policy schedule, policy cover, cover use, cover note, theft cover, windscreen cover, comprehensive cover, 
>   breakdown cover, commercial vehicle policy, commercial vehicle, motor vehicle, 
>   vehicle policyholder, vehicle insurer, insured vehicle

and I am trying to build a taxonomy that suggests that the first 3 phrases, for example, are under the same node (belong to the same level)

Comment: Can you provide code you're using, an an example data set, and the desired result?

Comment: Edit your question to add details, please.

Comment: I am using mallet implementaion from command window, I am using the following command line:
bin/mallet  run cc.mallet.topics.tui.HierarchicalLDATUI --input my_corpus.mallet --output-state topic-statehlda.txt
I managed to get the topic-statehlda.txt which contains all the topic paths for the words and I have also visualized it. Some terms occur in multiple topics so that is why I am interested in the word-topic distribution to be able to select the most representative ones.
I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I added some details but I hope it made things clearer not more confusing! Thanks for your edits!